# requests-oauthlib auto refresh Bearer token in client credentials flow?

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the python requests-oauthlib package to connect to the Microsoft Graph. I am using the OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials flow.

The following simplified code works perfectly fine:

```py
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id='myclientid')

token_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token"
msgraph = OAuth2Session(client=client)

msgraph.fetch_token(
    token_url = token_url,
    client_secret = 'myclientsecret',
    scope='https://graph.microsoft.com/.default')

response = msgraph.get(
    url="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@mydomain.com/messages")
```

While this works, the Bearer access token in this case is only valid for 1 hour.  The requests-oauthlib package has [support for refreshing tokens](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#all-define-the-token-token-saver-and-needed-credentials) but it seems limited to token types that come with separate refresh tokens.  The client credentials flow as used with the Microsoft Graph only issues an access_token.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to make the requests-oauthlib refresh the token automatically in this use case or do I need to manually track the age of my token and explicitly refresh it as needed?
2. I'm not wedded to requests-oauthlib so if there is a better library that accomplishes the auto-refreshing I'd be interested in using it.

Comment: Does this help you? If so I will add it as an answer - uses decorators. https://medium.com/@vinicius.ronconi/using-python-decorators-to-handle-expired-oauth-tokens-55e78316a188 (You can stick with your lib.)

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is by design (and aligns with the OAuth spec). The only OAuth grants that support Refresh Tokens are [Authorization Code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1) and [Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3). The [Implicit](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2) and [Client Credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4) grants only return an Access Token.

More importantly, since the Client Credentials flow isn't interactive, there is no need for Refresh Tokens. You simply request a new token when the old one expires.

Comment: Totally understand...was curious if there was library support to handle the details of tracking the expiration of the token and requesting a new one...or if I had to take care of that myself.

Comment: There are literally thousands of OAuth libraries out there. Personally, I just handle it myself.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there is still no built-in way to do this automatically using requests-oauthlib. There is a ticket about it on their GitHub with a couple of different ideas on how to do it, but nothing out of the box: https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/issues/260

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it seems unanswered, so please allow me to give it a try.

My initial answer was:

> I dare make the hypothesis, reading your mention of lack of refresh token, that you did not add `offline_access` in your requested `scope` - if you want it to be part of the answer from the Microsoft authentication service, you have to (please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#token-response and the various pages around for more details).

which was indeed totally irrelevant for the scenario used, as commented by Mark, and also clearly stated in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/resilience-daemon-app#cache-and-store-tokens:

> It is important that applications use the "expires_in" property to determine the lifespan of the token.

So as an answer to your question 2., the above link also suggests the use of [MSAL (MS Authentication Library)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python):

> MSAL implements and follows [best practices for caching and storing tokens] automatically.

what the [why use MSAL wiki page](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Why-use-MSAL-Python) seems to confirm:

> It also adds value by [...] maintaining a token cache and refreshes tokens for you when they are close to expire. You don't need to handle expiration on your own.

For your question 1., I indeed did not find a standard way in `requests-oauthlib` to do so, either.

In this kind of situation, I usually don't monitor the age of the token, but just catch the 401 return code and fetch a new token.

To do so, I found suitable to tweak the first example of the [Requests-OAuthlib - OAuth 2 Workflow - refreshing tokens](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#first-define-try-catch-tokenexpirederror-on-each-request) section, replacing their call to `refresh_token(refresh_url, **extra)` by a new call to `fetch_token()`.

What I usually use in order to avoid repeating the `try...except...` code piece, is to put it in a wrapper decorator (got a good inspiration in https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#a-few-real-world-examples ) around my API-calling functions / methods.

Hope this time it helps more...

Comment: thanks for the comment but for AzureAD client credentials flow, refresh tokens aren't generated:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

"As a side note, refresh tokens will never be granted with this flow as client_id and client_secret (which would be required to obtain a refresh token) can be used to obtain an access token instead."

Comment: My bad, Mark, I misread your initial request - sorry for this and thanks for your patient comment. Let me edit and propose an alternate answer, more suitable.